# how to debug tf2 in general and transformer in particular

Tags: tensorflow2.0, transformer-model

Looking for advice about a debugger for a TF2 model.
I would like to train the following transformer model
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/transformer/v2
on my own data.
My problem is that I have difficulty figuring out shape of data returned by the _parse_example function from the [data_pipeline.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/transformer/v2/data_pipeline.py) file. To start with [Pydev](https://www.pydev.org/) doesn't brake inside _parse_example function, neither does [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), which appears to be using [Pydev](https://www.pydev.org/) internally. The options offered by TensorBoard 2.0.0 seem to be applicable to TF1, not TF2:

> 1. sess = tf.Session()
>      sess = tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession(sess, "localhost:6064")
>      sess.run(my_fetches)
> 2. hook = tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugHook("localhost:6064")
>      my_estimator.fit(x=x_data, y=y_data, steps=1000, monitors=[hook])
> 3. keras.backend.set_session(
>      tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession(tf.Session(), "localhost:6064"))
>      model.fit(...)

So what tool can I use to see tensor's data and its shape? Option 2 from the above list seems to make sense, except for the fact that I don't see a call for my_estimator.fit from transformer's implementation for TF2.

My environment was created in Ubuntu 18.04 using anaconda: 
conda create -n mytest tensorflow-gpu.
I use Eclipse with PyDev plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of problem are you debugging in your transformer model? Looks like it's shape-related from your description. As you pointed out, the tf_debug features are incompatible with TensorFlow 2.0. But the tensorflow team is working on new TF 2.0-compatible debugging features. The features are not quite ready yet. But I'll make a note to update thread once they are.

Comment: The model isn't mine, it is Google's. As stated in the initial post, I merely want to train it on my own data and for that I need a way to find out format of data that model is written to process.  Since you're from Google, perhaps you might be the best person to point to the tool programmers at Google use to debug TF2 code.